# pymongo fails with error 'sys' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, django, mongodb, pymongo

I have a Django app that queries mongodb.

`requirements.txt`:

```
# other dependencies
pymongo==4.1.0
```

View:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://*****@****.mongodb.net/test_db?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
```

When this line is executed, the Django server throws the following error:

```
venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymongo/uri_parser.py, line 467, in parse_uri 
Exception: name 'sys' is not defined
```

How do I fix this error? I'm on Python3.9 and latest Django.

Comment: Looks like there is a bug in that version https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/pull/920. Try downgrading to an earlier version until a fixed version is released

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for *mongodb+srv://* URIs requires [dnspython](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dnspython):

use `pip install pymongo[srv]`